# still no way to initialize private static field in .h files?

Tags: c++

I have `Commons.h` file that contains "general" structures and classes declarations. Among others it contains such class declaration (only `static int nInstrument` is important, you can ignore the rest):

```
class Instrument
{
public:

    int Id() {
        return _id;
    }

    int GateId() {
        return _gateId;
    }

    const std::string& const ClassCode() const {
        return _classCode;
    }

    const std::string& const Ticker() const {
        return _ticker;
    }

    Instrument(int gateId_, std::string classCode_, std::string ticker_)
    {
        _gateId = gateId_;
        _classCode = classCode_;
        _ticker = ticker_;
        _id = nInstrument;
        std::cout << "New Instrument created << " << _ticker << " id = " << _id << std::endl;
        ++nInstrument;
    }

private:
    static int nInstrument;
    int _id;
    int _gateId;
    std::string _classCode;
    std::string _ticker;
};
```

I need to initialize `static int nInstrument;` with `0`. It's easy If I have `Commons.cpp` file as answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members) question. But I don't ave `Commons.cpp` file and I don't want to create it just to put one line `int Instrument::nInstrument = 0;`

I want to double check that `C++11` or future standart still doesn't have such feature? So I have to add `cpp` just to put one initialization line?

Comment: c++11 has "constexpr" keyword which can be used to initialize static const members inline

Comment: It should also be possible to put the initialization into any compilation unit that uses the header. But creating the cpp is easier to understand for others

Comment: @EdHeal i typed a question to improve my knoledge :)

Comment: You can put that line in any file; it doesn't have to be Commons.cpp.

Comment: @bobah could you give an example?

Comment: @javapowered Aren't all static members initialized to zero by default?

Comment: The value has to be stored somewhere, which is why you need to define it in a c(pp) file. Putting them in a header would cause them to be defined in every cpp that includes that header. The only exception are templates, which have to be fully defined in a header, you could make a workaround using them.

Comment: @bobah but it looks like OP wants to be able to modify the static at runtime.

Comment: you can use `#ifdef`s in your header to make it work (and small changes to your build script), but I'd advise against this

Comment: I just want something like `static int nInstrument = 0;`. I can do it in `C#` for example. BTW Not sure if static int is initialized by default to `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++11 has this kind of feature, but the most common compiler do not support it (yet). I tested that with XCode and VS2013. I got another solution, based on a question I already asked yesterday.

you have to form the attribute into a method:

```
class Instrument
{
 // your stuff

static int getInstrument()
{
   static int nInstrument=1234;
   return nInstrument;
}

};
```

This is header only. You can even extend that, look at the answers at:
[How to change a behavior for all instances of a class in a header only class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976500/how-to-change-a-behavior-for-all-instances-of-a-class-in-a-header-only-class)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yep, but I wanted to stick to the question. I added a link where that is described.

Answer (score 2):

If want want to have a static variable into a header only, you may use the following in your class:

```
static int& nInstrument() { static int s_i = 0; return s_i; }
```

Comment: @riv not with my compiler (VS2012 and VS2013)

Comment: I just tried `static int test() { static int val = 0; return val++; }` with VS2010 and it printed 0 twice when called from different source files. Was something changed regarding this behavior?

Comment: @riv give me a second, I check that with 2012.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the part that said "in your class". That indeed works in VS2010.

Comment: @riv yep. I wrote a short sample. It even works when you use it as a function with the inline keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workaround using templates (which allow instantiating static members directly in a header file):

```
class Instrument
{
  template<class T>
  struct Counter { static int value; };
  int _id;
public:
  Instrument()
    : _id(Counter<int>::value++)
  {}
  int id() { return _id; }
};
int Test::Counter<int>::value = 1;
```